# PostgreSQL Get all rows where its id is not anywhere in another column for a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

```
--------------+-------------------+
           id |         parent_id |
--------------+-------------------|
           18 |            <null> |
           20 |            <null> |
           25 |                18 |
--------------+-------------------+
```

I want my query to select all ids where its id doesn't exist in parent_id column. How would I go about doing that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Easiest way is to do use `NOT EXISTS` to return those id's not found in the parent_id column:

```
select id
from tablename t1
where not exists (select 1 from tablename t2
                  where t2.parent_id = t1.id)
```

`NOT IN` may also be used, but be careful, NULL's have to be taken care of:

```
select id
from tablename
where id not in (select parent_id from tablename
                 where parent_id is not null)
```